# Create a column with counts of values from multiple columns (if any)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with date columns:``

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'_id':['633739b043e8750c660feabd'] + ['63373966bf5eb50c6d593b1f'] + ['633738aa43e8750c660fe90e'] + ['63373853bf5eb50c6d5938c1'],

'2022-10-01':['1', '0', '0', '2'],
'2022-10-02':['0', '1', '0', '0'],
'2022-10-03':['2', '8', '3', '9'],
'2022-10-04':['0', '0', '0', '2'],
'2022-10-05':['9', '0', '0', '2'],
'2022-10-06':['1', '0', '3', '2'],

})
```

I need to get the counts in another column if the Id's date column has a value in it.

The result should look like this:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'_id':['633739b043e8750c660feabd'] + ['63373966bf5eb50c6d593b1f'] + ['633738aa43e8750c660fe90e'] + ['63373853bf5eb50c6d5938c1'],
    '2022-10-01':['1', '0', '0', '2'],
    '2022-10-02':['0', '1', '0', '0'],
    '2022-10-03':['2', '8', '3', '9'],
    '2022-10-04':['0', '0', '0', '2'],
    '2022-10-05':['9', '0', '0', '2'],
    '2022-10-06':['1', '0', '3', '2'],
    'No_of_Days':['4', '2', '2', '5']
})
```

Sorry the image was not being uploaded due to server error So I have added a sample codes. It's simple but still I am struggling as I am new to this.

Comment: The good news is that adding sample code is the correct way to ask questions.  Try to avoid posting images of code or data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the index as `_id`, then convert the rest of the df to integer and take the row-wise sum of values greater than zero.

```
df['No_of_Days'] = df.set_index('_id').astype(int).gt(0).sum(1).values
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! But if have many columns in the dataframe which consists of different datatypes, how can I modify this?

Comment: you could check out `select_dtypes` but the way you posted your sample data, your integers are actually strings.  If that is really the case you're need to manually drop columns prior to doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am putting all date column values in list and counting zeros in it. like `[1,0,2,0,9,1]` so `2 time zero` and total `6` days so `6-2 = 4` will be `No of days`.

Code:

```
df['No_of_Days'] = [len(i[1:]) - i[1:].count('0') for i in df.values.tolist()]
```

or

```
df['No_of_Days'] = [len(i[1:]) - i[1:].count('0') for i in df.values.tolist()] if 'No_of_Days' not in df else df['No_of_Days']
```

df

Comment: I tried this but the rows which had no 0 values were not being counts. Other than that it was working fine.

Comment: might be your 0 type is int so just try by .count(0) without ''.